# In C# is ID / OK ever to be used?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

With standard naming conventions is there ever a scenario that it is correct to use ID or OK in all capitals?

Comment: wouldn't that depend on your coding standards? To be honest: it doesn't really matter.

Comment: depends on your standard naming convention.

Comment: What is wrong with you close Nazi's, this is a very very specific and direct question.

Comment: Seems they assume that because they don't have an answer there can't be an answer. Fallacy of Ignorance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. According to the .NET Framework design guidelines, the correct capitalization is `Id` and `Ok` as these are abbreviations, not acronyms.

However, if you already have shipping DLLs which already use `ID` or `OK` then you should not change them as it will break consumers. Hence why the .NET Framework has some instances of these capitalizations, for example.

Comment: Are the "NET Framework design guidelines" the "standard naming convention" (+1 anyway, cause it matches my opinion)

Comment: ...and of course the .NET Framework never breaks its own guidelines! lol!

Comment: @Jodrell - Microsoft wrote the .NET Framework and the C# language, so I'd consider their official guidelines to be about as standard as it gets ;-)

Comment: @Mitch - Sometimes these guidelines aren't implemented until after things have already shipped. From what I remember, the Id/Ok guideline was actually implemented post .NET 1.0 *because* it shipped with a mixture of the two capitalizations as nobody had consider this rule until it was too late. So they decided to take the next best approach and ensure that future code was more consistent.

Comment: @Greg: I wasn't refering to that one specifically.